# Xpath for href element

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to click on the below href element,which is present among similar href elements.

```
<a id="oldcontent" href="listDetails.do?camp=1865"><u>Re-Call</u></a>
```

Can anyone provide me xpath to click the above href link?

Comment: selenium.click("xpath=//a[@href=\"listDetails.do?camp=1865\"]");   does not work

Comment: selenium.click("xpath=//a[@href='listDetails.do?camp=1865']"); does not work

Answer (score 30):

Try below locator.

```
selenium.click("css=a[href*='listDetails.do'][id='oldcontent']");
```

or

```
selenium.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'listDetails.do') and @id='oldcontent']");
```

Answer (score 7):

This works properly try this code-

```
selenium.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'listDetails.do') and @id='oldcontent']");
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get you the generic link:

```
selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'listDetails.do')")).Click();
```

If you want to have it specify a parameter then you will have to test for each one:

```
...
int i = 1;

selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'listDetails.do?camp=" + i.ToString() + "')")).Click();
...
```

The above could utilize a for loop which navigates to and from each camp numbers' page, which could verify a static list of camps.

Please excuse if the code is not perfect, I have not tested myself.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
//a[@id='oldcontent']/u[text()='Re-Call']
```

Answer (score 1):

for me worked //a[text()='Re-Call']

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me:

```
//a[contains(@href,'logout')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works fine.

```
//a[@id='oldcontent']
```

If you've tried certain ones and they haven't worked, then let us know, otherwise something simple like this should work.

Comment: There are multiple tags with same id,so am not using that.i want to pick it up using href value itself

Comment: selenium.click("css=a[href='listDetails.do?camp=236767']"); also does not work :-(

Comment: OK, what about `//a[@href='listDetails.do?camp=1865']`, note that it looks like the integer at the end is a unique ID, so you will need to cater for this. Do you get the element returned if you do a blanket contains search? `//a[contains(@href, 'listDetails.do')]`

Comment: Yes i need to pick up based on the unique id at the end of the listDetails.do?camp=1865,since all hrefs have sommon string listDetails.do?camp..Only integer differs

Comment: selenium.click("xpath=//a[@href='listDetails.do?camp=1865']");  does not work..Can anyone suggest solution

Comment: What browser do you use? Works fine using Chrome v22. Does it find the element at all or just not click on it?

Comment: Am using IE8.may be its not finding the element

Comment: Have you set up IE8 according to: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver  (the 'Required Configuration' section)

Comment: FYI if there are multiple elements with the same ID then you have a bigger issue as you have invalid elements.  If you have any JavaScript code on the page calling `document.getElementById(id);` you will get inconsistent results depending on the browser/version. I would **HIGHLY** recommend fixing the invalid DOM first.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to locate anchor elements is to use `link=Re-Call`:

```
selenium.click("link=Re-Call");
```

It will work..